# Рекурсия. Разница в передаче аргументов методу

Tags: java, рекурсия

Делаю через рекурсию перевод чисел в двоичную систему. Не могу понять, в чем разница между

```
static void bin(int num){    
    if (num >= 2){
        num = num / 2;//неправильно работает
        bin(num);    
    }    
    System.out.print(num%2);
}
```

и

```
static void bin(int num){
    if (num >= 2){
        bin(num / 2);//корректно работает            
    }       
    System.out.print(num%2);
}
```

Comment: В первом случае вы меняете num. А потом выводите его. А во втором случае не меняете. И выводите.

Comment: не понимаю, я же и там и там число делю на 2. Только в первом случае до передачи в метод, а во втором во время передачи в метод

Comment: Во втором случае num не меняется. Меняется это когда есть =.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Побуду вашим дебаггером =)

---

### **Пример**: число 100

**Первый случай**

**1.1** Вход в bin с числом 100

**1.2** Присвоение переменной num числа 50 (100 / 2)

(В предыдущем входе осталось число 50, так как поменяли переменную num) `50 % 2 = 0`

**2.1** Вход в `bin` с числом 50

**2.2** Присвоение переменной `num` числа 25 (50 / 2)

(В предыдущем входе осталось число 25, так как поменяли переменную num) `25 % 2 = 1`

**3.1** Вход в `bin` с числом 25

**3.2** Присвоение переменной `num` числа 12 (25 / 2)

(В предыдущем входе осталось число 12, так как поменяли переменную num) `12 % 2 = 0`

...

---

**Второй случай**

**1.1** Вход в `bin` с числом 100

**2.1** Вход в `bin` с числом 50 (100 / 2) (В предыдущем входе осталось число 100) `100 % 2 = 0`

**3.1** Вход в `bin` с числом 25 (50 / 2) (В предыдущем входе осталось число 50) `50 % 2 = 0`

**4.1** Вход в bin с числом 12 (25 / 2) (В предыдущем входе осталось число 25) `25 % 2 = 1`

...

Answer (score 0):

В первом примере вы изменяете `num` (делите на 2, если точнее), а значит остаток от деления вы выводите не от вашего `num`, а от уже измененного.

Ваш первый пример "эквивалентен" (если очень грубо) такому коду:

```
static void bin(int num){
    if (num >= 2){
        bin(num / 2);//корректно работает            
    }       
    System.out.print((num/2)%2);
}
```